# Is it possible to consume the Application Catalog Web Services Point from a custom application in the internet?

Tags: windows, sccm, configuration-management

I have a scenario where will have a server running Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager (I'm sure the latest available version), and I need to allow users to install applications to their machines from the internet, via a custom application.

I have very little experience with domains and enterprise-level user/software management, and to this point I know almost nothing about SSCM, but I've made some reseach and found out about the Application Catalog Web Site Point feature of SCCM.

What I need to do is the same as the Application Catalog Web Site Point, however due to some business rules I need to create a custom application. I've read that the Application Catalog Web Site Point is powered by the Application Catalog Web Services Point.

So I would like to use the Application Catalog Web Services Point to power my custom application and allow the Application Catalog to be accessed from the internet. Is that possible?

Is the Application Catalog Web Services Point open to people to create their own implementations of the Application Catalog Web Site Point? If so, is there a documentation to the API? What are the resources one can use to understand the Application Catalog Web Services Point and how to consume it?

I've found the official documentation offered by Microsoft to be rather scarce and vague about the Application Catalog Web Services Point capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SCCM there in your environment, then you're surely OK with this request. You don't need to do any more development with using APIs because SCCM roles Application Catalog WebSite point role can be configured for accepting clients connections from Internet.

You can easily [create a custom application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/apps/deploy-use/create-applications) by using SCCM admin console. [Install Application Web Service and Website roles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/apps/plan-design/plan-for-and-configure-application-management#configure-software-center-and-the-application-catalog-windows-pcs-only), and [deploy the application to specific user collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/apps/deploy-use/deploy-applications#deploy-an-application) so that users will be able to access the application via Application Catalog Web Site.

You can configure the Application Catalog web service role and the Application Catalog website role to use HTTPS for additional security on the intranet.

More information about [Concepts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712282.aspx#BKMK_Site_System_Roles) in SCCM:
`Application Catalog Web Service Point`: A role that Provides software information to the Application Catalog WebSite from the Software Library.
`Application Catalog WebSite Point`: A Role that provides users with a list of available software from the Application Catalog.